# using routing and adding place on map features,are they part of standard package?

Tags: android, ios

We need to know the list of API's which can be used to:
1-Add place on Map
2-Using the route features so user can reach to this place (destination)..also we need to know if packages for these API's....

Comment: you can use google direction api and places API

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can surely use all the above mentioned features. You can refer this link by developer android website https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/ .

Answer (score 0):

In ios, you can also do it by using the native Apple MapKit methods.

For adding pins:

`func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

And for creating routes, here's a sample code:

```
let transportType: MKDirectionsTransportType = (transportType == .car) ? .walking : .automobile
    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

    let sourcePLacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: (view.annotation?.coordinate)!, addressDictionary: nil)

    directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePLacemark)
    directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    directionRequest.transportType = transportType

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate { (response, error) in

        guard let response = response else {

            if let error = error {

                print(error)
            }

            return
        }

        let route = response.routes.first
        self.mapView.add((route?.polyline)!, level: .aboveRoads)
    }
```